# Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2 fetch tasklists error

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0

```
    ASP.NET Tasks API – OAuth2 Sample

Click the button below to authorize this application/list all TaskLists and Tasks. 




The request 'Google.Apis.Requests.Request(list @ https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists)' has failed. The service tasks has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiRequestException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError 
Not Found [404] 
Errors [ 
Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] 
] 
---> System.Net.WebException: 远程服务器返回错误: (404) 未找到。 
  在 System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
  在 Google.Apis.Requests.Request.InternalEndExecuteRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 位置 c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_release\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\Request.cs:行号 311 
  --- 内部异常堆栈跟踪的结尾 --- 
  在 Google.Apis.Requests.Request.AsyncRequestResult.GetResponse() 位置 c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_release\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\Request.cs:行号 285 
  在 Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.GetResponse() 位置 c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_release\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:行号 179 
  在 Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Fetch() 位置 c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_release\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:行号 199 
  在 Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2._Default.FetchTaskslists() 位置 F:\download\google-api-dotnet-client-1.3.0-beta.samples\Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2\Default.aspx.cs:行号 125
© 2011 Google Inc
```

I ran the sample and i got this. What wrong with that?
the tasks api has been opened, and i got authorization, but i cannot fetch tasklist,why?

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be registered [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

And it should be registered for the scope where you send the access token in return for data. Check the link, register the app and get your client credentials. Then register for the relevant scope.

And add more information to your question!! What are you using, what is the code etc,